# Why is the word 'always' written with only one 'L'?

Tags: orthography

Does anybody know why the word *always* is written with one *L*, although it is formed by putting together two words, *all* and *ways*?

Comment: For the same reason as _altogether_ and _albeit_ are written with one _l_: because the compound was treated as one word while spelling was still fluid, and happened to get fixed with a different choice from _all_.

Comment: How about 'already"? How about 'all right'?

Comment: And _alone_, and _also_, and _lone(ly)_, where even the a is missing.

Comment: The other `l` ran away long ago and has never been seen since. It said it was tired of hanging out with Al and his ways.

Comment: For the same reason that _all_ is written with two L's. I.e, arbitrary spelling rules. There's no reason that it couldn't be spelt AL, after al; the final /l/ is not long. Executive summary: Do not expect any regularity about English spelling, nor any useful answer for questions about why words are spelled the way they are instead of some other way. English spelling is 400-year-old technology; it's not **sposta** be regular. It's like a street in an old part of the world, like India or Europe; you enjoy the sights and you're grateful it's not broken down completely yet.

Answer (score 2):

Middle English use of the word "all" and "al" were both recognized.  14th century constructions likely appeared as both "allways" and "always".

In general, the codification of something like this often comes down to a single text that chose one construction.  It is possible that something like the King James Bible or a particular author chose one spelling which was later emulated and eventually taken as the rule.